# How to print the Indian Rupee Symbol in java

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode

I tried to display rupee symbol by using below code. But in output I'm getting a box symbol instead of rupee:

[image: sample]

Code:

```
public class Applet extends JApplet {
    public static final String RUPEE = "\u20B9";

    public void init () {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel b = new JLabel("rupee : " + RUPEE +123);
        b.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        add(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: change the encoding format look in to this http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0136.html

Comment: This works fine on macOS. Most likely the font you are using doesn't contain that character.

Comment: Thank you it's working fine after updating

Answer (score 3):

This box symbol is usually a sign that your font doesn't support this character. There's nothing you can do short of using a font that supports it instead of the current one.

Newer versions of Arial support this, so maybe your system needs an update.